# Get quantity of specific item (simple product) in cart by ID

Tags: shopping-cart, quantity

Seems straight forward but I am seeing every scenario on Google except for the one I need. I just need to "query" Magento (or its quote model?) and return that number **in the shopping cart** based on the ID I provide via PHP. I believe Magento loops through the product data as line items so I can't lock down the qty field that is plainly visible right next to the item I just added to the cart.

Background: I have created an upsell module I've and I need to multiply the upsells by the number of base products in the cart.

Comment: An ID of what?  You probably mean product ID but you didn't actually say.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, there are many ways to select the specific products or product IDs of the cart. Whatever method you use is dependent upon what your needs are. I will summarize the last lines of code that allowed me to provide an ID anywhere on the cart page and return the qty of that cart product:

```
$_item = 123; // Whatever your product ID is. You can use any method like $_product->getProductId() to get to this point.
$_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item);
$theqty = $this->escapeHtml($_product->getQty());
echo $theqty; // Prints quantity out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get product quantity without looping all items:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
$qty = $_item->getQty();
```